# Other user can read helvetica neue in browser without install the font?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have to use 'helvetica neue' as my asp.net default font. After installed in my pc, I able to add the font into my css, and it is worked while run the web application at local. But after I deployed into server. The 'helvetica neue' font is not working. Is it have to install the font on user computer?

My CSS:

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.otf'); } 

body
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    /*font-family: HelveticaNeueLT Pro 63 MdEx;*/
    font-family: Delicious, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 76%; /* all font sizes are related to this initial 'small' font-size setting (which is more or less 12pt) */
    min-width: 730px; /* min- and max-width don't work in IE Win 6 and below */
    max-width: 1250px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with absolute path?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by absolute path?

Comment: Were you using a different browser to test this? Your `@font-face` declaration won't work on all the different browsers.

Comment: I was try using Chrome and IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 by using IE developer tool. But the result still same. I run at my local. All browser is can display the font.

Comment: absolute path is for instance, `http://www.yourdomain.com/css/images` and relative path is `../css/images` - @HowardHee

Answer (score 0):

your @font-face is not complete, and you need some more files:

1. EOT for IE,
2. SVG fir Ipad,
3. WOFF for FireFox
4. TTF/OTF for the rest

You can create those font files at [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Delicious';
 src: url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.eot');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Delicious';
 src: url(//:) format('no404'), 
 url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.woff') format('woff'), 
 url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.ttf') format('truetype'), 
 url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.svg#Delicious') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I received error, "format('woff'), is not a valid value for 'src' properties".-@Mark

Comment: Current versions of Firefox use TTF/OTF without any issues - so there's no need for the WOFF. For TTF support generally, see http://caniuse.com/ttf

Comment: Error Message "Validation (CSS 2.1): 'url('../css/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-CnO.otf'),' is not a valid value for the 'src' property." I think the issue is because of 'src'.- @gzost